# how to add text for the dots in ggplot graph R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to add the numbers for the dots in my graph. thanks for the help!

```
percentage.no.work <- cleanData %>% group_by(AREA) %>%          
  summarise(percentage = mean(ESTIMATED.CITY.UNEMPLOYMENT))

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data=percentage.no.work, aes(x=AREA, y=percentage), alpha=0.6, color="purple", size=2) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  theme_minimal() + ggtitle("Percentage Estimated City Unemployment") + 
  ylab("Percentage")
```

Comment: Please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a little made-up data, you can add text labels like this. Note, you also need the `aes()` in `ggplot` rather than `geom_point` and a `group = 1` so that you get the `geom_smooth` rendered.

```r
library(tidyverse)

tribble(
  ~AREA, ~percentage,
  "a", 0.2,
  "b", 0.4
) |>
  ggplot(aes(AREA, percentage, group = 1), alpha = 0.6, color = "purple", size = 2) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(aes(label = percentage), nudge_x = 0.1) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  theme_minimal() +
  ggtitle("Percentage Estimated City Unemployment") +
  ylab("Percentage")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>